# Most frequent words

Tags: java

What's the most efficient way in Java to get the 50 most frequent words with their frequency out of a text?

I want to search around ~1,000,000 texts with each have around ~10,000 words and hope that it works in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Doubtful to the homework comment.

Comment: This sounds more like an algorithmic question than a java question.

Comment: Efficiency is a loaded word - do you mean in terms of execution time, memory required, time-to-code-in-java ("efficient use of programmer"), or a mix of the three?

Comment: No, it's not homework. I afterwards want to compare the most frequent words of different texts to find similarities between the texts.

Comment: You will probably end up with sets of "you", "will", "with", "of", "and", and suchlike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most efficient would probably be using a [Patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_trie) that links to a [max-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). Every time you read a word, `find` it on the trie, go to the heap and `increase-key`. If it's not in the trie, `add` it and set its key in the heap appropriately.

With a [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap), `increase-key` is `O(1)`.

---

A not so unreasonable solution is to use a `Map<String, Integer>`, adding the count every time a word is encountered, and then custom-sorting its `entrySet()` based on the count to get the top 50.

If the `O(N log N)` sort is unacceptable, use [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the top 50 in `O(N)`.

---

Which technique is better really depends on what you're asking for (i.e. the comment whether this is more of an `[algorithm]` question than a `[java]` question is very telling).

The `Map<String, Integer>` followed by selection algorithm is most practical, but the Patricia trie solution clearly beats it in space efficiency alone (since common prefixes are not stored redundantly).

Comment: The number of unique words U in a large text with N words is typically very low (N >> U). The map wins every time, as the words in U are not large enough for a PTrie to shine, and is much simpler to implement. Also, O(N) >> O(U log U): sorting is comparatively cheap.

Comment: By your notation, the Ptrie would contain `U` words, so I'm not sure what your complaint is.

Comment: PTries are not faster than Hashmaps for small string (=word) sizes, and are therefore not worth the trouble. I would definitely use them if I needed to find long substrings; but this problem you can solve with out-of-the-shelf containers.

Comment: Why not simply combine a hash map with a max-heap?

Comment: @Eyal: HashMap would store each word as keys as whole strings; Ptrie would remove redundancy in storing common prefixes.

Comment: @tuxuci: You're mixing up your symbols. I use `N` because that's the convention, e.g. "mergesort is `O(N log N)`". I use `N` to denote the number of elements in the data structure, be it the map or the ptrie. That is, my `N` is your `U`.

Comment: @poly: my whole point is that N and U are so different that time-with-full-sort = time-with-selection-sort for all practical purposes, making "programmer efficiency" favor the easiest-to-implement option. I use 'U' to explicitly distinguish it from 'N' (which I also use, as per convention).

Comment: @tuxuci: fair enough, but if this is a "most efficient algorithm" question regardless of practicality of implementation, `O(U)` clearly beats `O(U log U)` (and by the way, selection algorithm has nothing to do with selection sort).

Comment: Unless `U` is utterly massive, `O(UlogU)` is about as good as `O(U)`, enough so that the other parts of the cost that big-O notation hides can matter. (`log(10000000000)` is only 10.)

Comment: "`O(UlogU)` is about as good as `O(U)`" : not to a computer scientist/algorithmist. Also, one is clearly more "efficient" (OP's word) than the other.

Answer (score 4):

Following pseudocode should do the trick:

```
build a map<word, count>
build a tokenizer that gives you a word per iteration
for each word*,
   if word in map, increment its count
   otherwise add with count = 1
sort words by count
for each of the first 50 words,
   output word, frequency = count / total_words
```

This is essentially O(N), and what jpabluz suggested. However, if you are going to use this on any sort of "in the wild" text, you will notice lots of garbage: uppercase/lowercase, punctuation, URLs, stop-words such as 'the' or 'and' with very high counts, multiple variations of the same word... The right way to do it is to lowercase all words, remove all punctuation (and things such as URLs), and add stop-word removal and stemming at the point marked with the asterisk in the above pseudocode.

Comment: "This is essentially O(N)" - it is if `N` is the number of words in input. If `U` is the number of unique words, then "sort words by count" is `O(U log U)`. You can in fact get the top 50 (unordered) in just `O(U)` using selection algorithm.

Comment: Since N >> U for any but the briefest texts, O(N) will dominate over O(U log U). Yes, a max-heap shaves some time off, but the gain is very small, and it is not free (extra code complexity).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer is not unreasonable and is very practical (as I also mention it as an option in my answer), but OP asks for "most efficient", and obviously Ptrie is more space efficient than a map storing whole words as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance would be an O(n) algorithm, I would go for a text reader that will split the words and then, add it to an ordered tree, which you would order by number of appearences and link them to a word. After that just do a 50-iterations traverse to get the highest values.

Comment: How would adding to an ordered tree be O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

`O(n)`:

1. Count the number of words
2. Split your text word wise into list of words
3. Create a map of word=>number_of_occurences
4. Traverse the map and select max. 50.
5. Divide them by total number of words to get frequency

Of course some of this steps may be done at the same time or unnecessary depending on data structures you'll use.